# JSON data returns project name with array name

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary, codable

I have this type of data.

```
John Tylor  :  [StudentData.moreDetailsArray(type: "Full Time", status: "Graduated")]
```

I would like to print only John Tylor : Full Time : Graduated rather than printing project name along with array key.

Code is attached below:

```
struct StudentData: Decodable {

    let moreDetails: [moreDetailsArray]
    let id: Int
    let name: String

}

struct moreDetailsArray: Decodable {

    let type: String
    let status: String

}

func parseStudentData(){

        let url = URL(string: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/11mamq")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            do{
                if error == nil{
                    let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode([StudentData].self, from: data!)

                    for a in json! {
                        print("\(a.name)"  ," : ",  "\(a.moreDetails)")
                    }

                }
            } catch {
                print("error getting status: \(error)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s not JSON.

Comment: `a.moreDetails` is an array. so what do you expect to be printed if there is more than one moreDetailsArray values?

Comment: You need to show us the original JSON data, not some baked version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to `print` model. You need to `print` each property of your `moreDetailsArray` model.

**Code:**

```
print("\(a.name)"  ," : ",  "\(a.moreDetails.first!.type)" , " : ", "\(a.moreDetails.first!.status)")
```

Or you can do it without unwrapping and **print  in one string**:

```
if let type = a.moreDetails.first?.type, let status = a.moreDetails.first?.status {
    print("\(a.name) : \(type) : \(status)")
}
```

And you should rename your model objects as mentioned in another answers. It'll be good for your code readability and quality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think moreDetailsArray needs to be an array.

I would implement it like this:

```
struct Student: Decodable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let moreDetail: StudentoreDetail

    var description: String {
        return "\(name) : \(additionalInformation.description)"
    }
}

struct StudentAdditionalInfo: Decodable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let type: String
    let status: String

    var description: String {
        return "\(type) : \(status)"
    }
}
```

then all you need to do is:

```
guard let data = data, 
    let students = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Student].self, from: data) else {

     print("[DEBUG] - No data/json"
     return
} 

for student in students {
    print(student.description)
}
```

if your moreDetails actually is an array you can just select the first item if it exists.

```
struct Student: Decodable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let moreDetail: StudentMoreDetail

    var description: String {
        return "\(name) : \(moreDetail.first?.description)"
    }
}
```

**Additional Tips:**

1. Don't force unwrap i.e. `JSONDecoder().decode([StudentData].self, from: data**!**)`
2. Name new types such as classes, structs, enums etc in Proper case (uppercase first letter)
3. Try to follow the golden path, the guard statement can help you here.
4. Don't name things like moreDetailsArray that was a struct and not actually an array although you use it in an array

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to keep moreDetails as an array and are only interested in the first item in the array:

```
print("\(a.name) : \(a.moreDetails[0].type) : \(a.moreDetails[0].status)")
```

Also, the struct you have named moreDetailsArray isn't really an array. The property used to store this is an array, however. So I would suggest that you call the moreDetails property moreDetailsArray instead, and change the name of the struct to MoreDetails.

Answer (score 0):

Create model Like that using `Codable` Protocol

```
import Foundation

typealias Students = [Student]

struct Student: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let moreDetails: [MoreDetail]
}

struct MoreDetail: Codable {
    let type, status: String
}

// MARK: Convenience initializers

extension Student {
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Student.self, from: data)
    }

    init(_ json: String, using encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws {
        guard let data = json.data(using: encoding) else {
            throw NSError(domain: "JSONDecoding", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
        }
        try self.init(data: data)
    }

}

extension Array where Element == Students.Element {
    init(students  data: Data) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Students.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

**Use it like that :**

```
   func parseStudentData(){

        let url = URL(string: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/11mamq")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            if let data = data , let students =  try? Array.init(students: data){
                students.forEach({ (student) in
                    if student.moreDetails.count > 0{
                        print("\(student.name) : \(student.moreDetails[0].type) : \(student.moreDetails[0].status)")
                    }else{
                        print(student.name)
                    }
                })
            }
        }.resume()

    }
```